# Advice on designing a game

Tags: hardware, pi-2

Software dev here who has never done a hardware project before.  I was hoping to make a game that's usually called [pixilated](http://news.ebscer.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/QwertyPixelated1.png) or similar.  I would make a smallish (maybe 6x6) grid of [these](https://www.pololu.com/product/1074), and presumably having the pi run the game code.

I wrote the game code earlier this week for an Android app, so I would probably just have to change the UI code, and then also write a hardware layer.

My question is - am I being totally delusional?  Having never done any hardware work before but looking at some projects, it looks like there is a lot more to doing this than simple plug and play.

Would Arduino vs Raspberry Pi (or both?) make sense.  Would this game simply be beyond what a Pi can do?  Are there similar projects out there?

The game: Position (0,0) on the grid is "selected".  When you press a button's color (red, green, blue, etc), any node that is of that color, and directly north, south, east or west of a selected node also becomes selected.

Or from a website's description: The object of the game is to change the colour of the squares until the entire screen is a single solid colour. Starting with the square in the upper left corner you can change the colour of the blocks in order to match that of the surrounding squares. This is done repeatedly until the entire screen is a single colour.

Comment: Your revised question involves too many disparate aspects.  Again, this isn't a discussion forum.  If you have specific questions about specific issues, great -- but one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only doubt in my mind is in how you plan to drive the LEDs.  RGB LEDs require 3 GPIO per LED so you need a total of 6x6x3 or 108.  The Pi only has 27 usable GPIO.

So you will need an expansion port like the popular MCP23017, each one of which can drive 16 GPIO.  You can connect 8 to the Pi's I2C bus to provide 128 GPIO.

Alternatively you could use shift registers such as 74HC595N to achieve the same affect.

With both of these methods you will have to use solid colours, e.g. R, G, B, RG, RB, GB, RGB.  PWM to vary the brightness isn't really practical using these expansion chips from the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome advice.  Any thoughts on how to control input?  It looks like I could have up to 7 colors, though on a 6x6 that's clearly overkill.  Even so, should I just have 3 buttons?  Would those also just run through the GPIO?  (clearly a total novice here!)

Comment: @Timotheus You don't mention any input.  Could you add the details to your question?

Comment: While I'm not telling joan or anyone else to not answer you (and it is nice that she evidently will), please note [this is not a discussion forum](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour), meaning an open ended series of "Okay, so then..." interrogations are generally not appropriate.   This seems like a good answer to your question as originally written.  In future, if you subsequently think of an "okay but" please make it a new question, not  something to continuously tack on.

Comment: @joan edited the question!